# Can I answer to my own bounty question?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have put a bounty on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371549/jxta-p2p-application-over-internet).  I think I have found the answer only 6 hours are remaining for bounty to close. Can I answer the question and select it as correct answer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can always self-answer your question. But [don't expect to get your bounty back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/lost-reputation-after-answering-my-own-question-with-bounty) ;)

Comment: Does "don't expect to" means "you won't" or does it mean "you might not"? What I expect to happen and what actually happens are two different things. I don't see how this is an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: The answer is that you won't get your bounty back even if your question receives zero answers. It's totally bammer and it just happened to me. I think that you should get it back if nobody helps you at all. Especially if you solved the problem yourself with no help from the community.

Comment: You can't award a bounty to yourself.  Think of the bounty as paying for publicity, not necessarily paying for an answer.