# Can I win my own bounty placed on someone elses question?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Let's say I've got a question that the OP is slow at accepting an answer to, but my answer has the most votes.

If I were to put a bounty on their question, and the votes were not to change, would I win the bounty at the end of the time period? And would the question get marked as accepted?
If so, how much (net) reputation would I gain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost reputation after answering my own question with bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/lost-reputation-after-answering-my-own-question-with-bounty)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, a bounty can be awarded to the person who posted it, even on someone else's question. However, there are some things you should know before that.

First off, if you had an answer there before you posted the bounty, then your answer is not eligible for any bounty auto-selection. Also, bounties are not related to acceptance, so it would be a futile effort on that ground anyway.

Second, awarding yourself the bounty is possible, but it results in a net loss of reputation - you do *not* get awarded the reputation if you assigned the bounty in the first place. Whether this occurs by you manually doing it or by auto-accept does not affect this result.

Comment: Wow, that's actually a really interesting question and a great answer!