# I got the reputation back from my own bounty

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, bounties

I know this isn't supposed to happen. I've just received the reputation from my own bounty.

What happened.

1. I placed a bounty on someone else's question.
2. I found an answer to this question.
3. I answered the question, and got up-voted.
4. I didn't like the other answer as it didn't help me so I didn't award the bounty.
5. When the time ended I got half the reputation back (25 points)

The question involved is: [How to compile a svn python binding for windows from the source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894744/4182705#4182705)

One of the reasons that I think that this is a bug is [Lost reputation after answering my own question with bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18841/lost-reputation-after-answering-my-own-question-with-bounty)

I'm happy for those 25 reputation points to be removed from my account if necessary. Although lets be perfectly honest I'd rather they were not.

Wes

Comment: The linked meta question is probably irrelevant.  That was asked before the changes to the bounty system.

Comment: It is a bug because the expected behavior is that you shouldn't earn the bounty. It is not easy or common for the auto-award to fall-through onto your own answer, which explains why this hasn't been observed until now. Good job on finding this bug. If I had to hazard a guess, Community being behind the award might explain why it didn't quite count as a self-award.

Comment: Just curious not complaining but why so many upvotes?

Comment: On a bug report, upvotes typically indicate "Hey, we agree this should get resolved. Ideally quickly". The score of a post has some measure of impact on the relative immediacy of attention that a bug report or feature request will get from the Team. So in the same vein that downvotes are used to try and prevent assumed bad ideas from happening, upvotes are used to expedite an implementation that is believed to be useful or important.

Comment: What @Grace says. Although the motivation for my +1 was more "hey, good catch!" than "this should be fixed urgently"

Comment: Let's give the author the 25 rep points he's going to lose back, so he's not feeling bad about reporting the bug. I just upvoted one of his questions. [Link to SO user.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/117421) 20 more to go.

Comment: @Georg thats very generous thank you, I'd rather though you don't upvote anything that isn't worthy of upvoting. Also I'm not sure if the points have actually been removed yet.

Comment: @Wes: They probably will get removed after the next recalc. Don't fear, I only upvote questions I deem worthy of an upvote. :)

Comment: @Georg Scholly I guess that didn't happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice find - there is now a unit test to ensure this doesn't happen again :)

Comment: Also, this fix will be pushed in tonight's build.