# Could I receive bounties back if the question hadn't the attention that was needed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I've opened a bounty of 50 reputation on one of my question: [How could I create gaze buttons using React VR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589115/how-could-i-make-gaze-buttons-using-react-vr) but it didn't receive an answer that could help me from any other Stack Overflow user. After research and development I've found an answer and answered my own question.

The bounty on this question will be lost because I couldn't receive it to anyone else. So my question is now: if a bounty haven't receive the attention that was needed to solve it, could I receive it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It dosen't work that way. Think of it as spending reputation on advertising, rather than a simple transaction of reputation for an answer.

Unfortunately if you can self answer, the bounty is still lost.

Comment: I found a strange thing on my question. My answer was accepted maby by a moderator or a computer and receive 15 reputation. The votes on the answer goes from 0 to 2 in a short time however it was answered 4 days ago. The question have received also one upvote. In totally good for **40 reputation** = 10 reputation points less size of my bounty.

Comment: Primarily coincidence

Comment: I don't think so, you couldn't recieve 15 reputation if your own question is accepted.

Comment: Well if its a bug, could be related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70713/i-got-the-reputation-back-from-my-own-bounty?rq=1 . Mods/system dosen't pick the correct answer, and you don't get the +15 for your own answer anyway.